# Using isset or @ to test/assign a superglobal variable

Tags: php, isset, superglobals

Can I use `@` instead of `isset` to assign or test superglobal variable ?

Use this :

```
$foo = intval(@$_POST['bar']);
```

Instead of this :

```
$foo = isset($_POST['bar']) ? intval($_POST['bar']) : 0;
```

works without generate a notice but maybe for some reasons, the use of `isset` is better than `@` ?

Comment: isset is cleaner programming style I think. But there shouldn't be any disadvantages...

Comment: error suppression in itself is a disadvantage.

Comment: @Yoshi To debug, maybe, but there exists `xdebug.scream`...

Comment: I would consider using error suppression a very hackish approach here. It clouds your actual intent.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`isset` with the ternary operator would be cleaner and easier to read. 
Error suppression on the other hand, has some overhead costs:

> I first built a simple test that would loop a million times accessing
>   a variable with and without the suppression operator prepended. The
>   differences were small, yet noticeable. Using the suppression operator
>   ended up taking 40% longer to execute.

Sources:

http://seanmonstar.com/post/909029460/php-error-suppression-performance
http://www.lunawebs.com/blog/2010/06/07/another-look-at-php-error-supression-performance/

Answer (score 3):

There's an alternative to using *@* for those of us who are tired of using isset() before pulling the value:

```
function iisset(&$var, $default = null) {
     return isset($var) ? $var : $default;
}
```

There is no notice generated for passing a non-existent array index as a reference. So for your example you would use:

```
$foo = intval(iisset($_POST['bar'], 0));
```

I wish PHP had a function like this built-in. The amount of *isset* checks followed immediately by the retrieval of that array index is so common that without a function like this there is a ridiculous amount of extra code.

**Update:**

PHP 7 now has a built-in operator known as the [null coalesce operator](http://php.net/manual/en/migration70.new-features.php#migration70.new-features.null-coalesce-op):

```
$foo = intval($_POST['bar'] ?? 0);
```